# Overloading method in webservice c#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, overloading

I have overloaded methods in one Webservice as below:

```
[SoapHeader("Authentication")]
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "DeferringTransaction", Description = "Deferring Transaction")]
    public WsResponse SendTransaction(WsDeferringTransaction wsDeferringTransaction)
    {
        factory.LoadSettings();
        WsResponse response = new WsResponse();
        response.ErrorCode = "Test";
        response.ReturnCode = 1;
        return response;
    }
    [SoapHeader("Authentication")]
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "ProcessedTransaction", Description = "Processed Transaction")]

    public WsResponse SendTransaction(WsProcessedTransaction wsProcessedTransaction)
    {
        factory.LoadSettings();
        WsResponse response = new WsResponse();
        response.ErrorCode = "Test";
        response.ReturnCode = 1;
        return response;
    }
```

But when I try to consume this webservice, the method SendTransaction appears with another name: SendTransaction and SendTransaction1

```
 ServiceReference1.WsDeferringTransaction wsDeferringTransaction = new ServiceReference1.WsDeferringTransaction()
        {
            CaptiveId = 1,
            TransactionDeferringId = 2
        };

        ServiceReference1.WsResponse r = ws.SendTransaction(u, wsDeferringTransaction);

        ServiceReference1.WsProcessedTransaction wsProcessedTransaction = new ServiceReference1.WsProcessedTransaction()
        {
            DocumentNumber = 4,
            TransactionSequenceNumber = 450
        };

        ServiceReference1.WsResponse r2 = ws.SendTransaction1(u,wsProcessedTransaction);
```

Is it possible to create overloaded methods and consume it with the same name? Can the problem be because of SoapHeader? By the way, I already have webServiceBinding with WsiProfiles.None:

```
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SOAP you cant ,  **Method names must have unique names** in the exported WSDL.

Depending on the technology you are using there are different ways to specify a method name. For example in WCF you could use the [OperationContract] attribute to specify a name .

else method overloading is easily implemented in web service class . Please follow the link to have a look : -

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/webservices/overloadinginwebservice.aspx